# Create a BitBucket Team repository using the api

Tags: repository, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I need to create a Team repository usign Bitbucket's API.

To create a user repository I use to do so:

```
$ curl -k -X POST -u username:passwd "https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories" -d "name=myrep"
```

How would I do the same but for a team?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This explains how it works with the [`repositories`](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-repositories/#api-repositories-workspace-repo-slug-post) endpoint of [API 2](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/repository-resource-423626331.html):

```
$ team=myteam
$ repo=repository
$ curl -X POST -v -u username:password -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/${team}/${repo} \
  -d '{"scm": "git", "is_private": "true", "fork_policy": "no_public_forks" }'
```

The difference from API 1 regarding how the data (-d) is handled is that API2 uses JSON format.

Comment: `password` can be a Bitbucket "app password". Hopefully it's not your account password.